# Why new array in Javascript not getting pushed by the results I got?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, push

I was working on Magic 8 ball on my site and had to write the code on JS.
Everything was fine until I decided to not get a random answer getting repeated 5 times.
So basically, I wanna have an array that contains 5 last results that I have gotten.

```
const responses = ["keep up", "no", "dont even think", 
"very doubtful", "outlook good", "my sources say no", 
"it is decidedly so", "dont count on it", "it is certain", 
"ask again later", "reply hazy, try again", "outlook not so good", 
"cannot predict now", "better not tell you now", "definetely - yes", "most likely"];

function randomly() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length);
    let result = responses[random];
    let lastfive = [];
    if (lastfive.includes(result)) {
        return randomly();
    }
    else {
        if (lastfive.length = 5) {
            lastfive.length = 0;
        }
        let neew=lastfive.push(result);
        console.log("bye:" + lastfive);
        return(result);
    }
}

})();
```

Comment: This new array contains only the last result by removing old ones. Where I got wrong?

Comment: `let lastfive=[];` creates a new array every time the function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
if(lastfive.length=5)
```

Probably should be:

```
if (lastfive.length === 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function, you're always returning the last random response it got thats why your always getting just one responese

So I hope you're okay with me editing the function. Here's the function iteratively

```js
const responses = ["keep up", "no", "dont even think", "very doubtful", "outlook good", "my sources say no", "it is decidedly so", "dont count on it", "it is certain", "ask again later", "reply hazy, try again", "outlook not so good", "cannot predict now", "better not tell you now", "definetely - yes", "most likely"];

function randomly() {
  let lastfive = [];

  while (lastfive.length < 5) { // While loop condition
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length);
    let result = responses[random];
    // Checking if result not in lastfive array
    if (!lastfive.includes(result)) lastfive.push(result); //pushing to lastfive
  }

  return lastfive; // returning the array
}

console.log(randomly());
```

And this is the same function recursively

```js
const responses = ["keep up", "no", "dont even think", "very doubtful", "outlook good", "my sources say no", "it is decidedly so", "dont count on it", "it is certain", "ask again later", "reply hazy, try again", "outlook not so good", "cannot predict now", "better not tell you now", "definetely - yes", "most likely"];

function randomly(five = []) {
  const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * responses.length);
  const result = responses[random];
  
  if (five.includes(result)) randomly(five);
  else {
    five.push(result);
    
    if (five.length < 5) randomly(five);
  }
  
  return five;
}

console.log(randomly())
```